# Expand Excel pivot table values by each month, given start and end date values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table in Excel related to item price given start and end date. Below is an example:

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNjDh.png)

```
ID  Start date  End date    Price
P-1 01/05/2019  31/12/2019   75.00 € 
P-1 01/02/2020  01/08/2020   80.00 € 
P-2 01/06/2019  01/08/2020   70.00 €
```

I need to create a pivot table that can expand this table by each month. My expected result is as below:

[Excel pivot table - expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5kwm.png)

```
ID  P-1
    
Month   Sum of Price
01/05/2019   75.00 € 
01/06/2019   75.00 € 
01/07/2019   75.00 € 
01/08/2019   75.00 € 
01/09/2019   75.00 € 
01/10/2019   75.00 € 
01/11/2019   75.00 € 
01/12/2019   75.00 € 
01/01/2020  
01/02/2020   80.00 € 
01/03/2020   80.00 € 
01/04/2020   80.00 € 
01/05/2020   80.00 € 
01/06/2020   80.00 € 
01/07/2020   80.00 € 
01/08/2020   80.00 € 
Total    1,160.00 €
```

I've tried to create this pivot table but I'm not able to expand the price by month as desired:

[Excel pivot table - current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BNZL.png)

```
ID  P-1
    
Month   Sum of Price
01/02/2019   80.00 € 
01/05/2019   75.00 € 
Total    155.00 €
```

Comment: Since you have overlapping ranges for P-1 `01/05/2019 to 31/12/2019` and `01/02/2019 to  01/08/2020`,   how do you decide which Price to display?  And why is there no price displayed for `1/1/2020`  That date is in the range of the 2nd P-1

Comment: Hi Ron, I’ve updated the start date of the second row from 01/02/2019 to 01/02/2020, thanks for notice that! For the 01/01/2020 there may be periods with price = 0€, in this case I keep them empty.

Comment: I do not believe a Pivot Table can expand the dates as you show. You will need to create a new table with the expanded dates. You can do this with Excel formulas (very complicated), VBA, or Power Query. Then you can filter and total your results as you show

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your comments, in this case I will go for one of these other approaches